# Call php script inside java activity after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, android-studio

I am parsing a `JSON` title, URL etc. from a `PHP` script. I want to give a reward with `PHP` script after the user click my link. Reward code -

```js
String awr = Config.Base_Url+"videos/award.php";
```

Now everything is working, there is just no reward, no call to my `PHP` script...
How do i need modify my script to get correct reward? My java activity -

```js
package com.uabclousy.pjanidemo;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.uabclousy.pjanidemo.app.App;
import com.uabclousy.pjanidemo.constants.Constants;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ItemsActivity extends BaseActivity  {

    private PrefManager prf;

    List<DataAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "https://pjani.com/ImageJsonData.php";

    String Image_Name_JSON = "image_title";

    String Image_Decription_JSON = "app_description";

    String Image_URL_JSON = "image_url";

    String App_URL_JSON = "app_url";

    String App_Message_JSON = "app_message";

    String App_Points = "app_points";
    String App_Id = "videoId";
    String App_sec = "id";

    public static final String EXTRA_VIDEO_ID = "id";
    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "id";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    ArrayList<String> AppmessageArrayListForClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);

        prf = new PrefManager(this);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        AppmessageArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);

        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        validate();

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ItemsActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                view = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(view != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked Item value.
                    RecyclerViewItemPosition = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                    // Showing RecyclerView Clicked Item value using Toast.
                    Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this, AppmessageArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String url = ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.get(RecyclerViewItemPosition);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.putExtra("points", App_Points);
                    intent.putExtra("vid", App_Id);
                    intent.putExtra("id", App_sec);
                    intent.putExtra("yourreq4", "fuck13");
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                return false;
            }



            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }


        });

    }

    void award_items(final String points, final String tostore, final String type){

        String awr = Config.Base_Url+"videos/award.php";

        final String v1 ="1";
        final String v0 ="0";
        final String v2 ="2";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, awr,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Enable this only on testing - yash
                        //Toast.makeText(VideosActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if(response.intern() == v1.intern()) {
                            Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this, points+" "+getString(R.string.points_received), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            prf.setBoolean(tostore, true);
                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        if(response.intern() == v0.intern()) {

                            Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this, getString(R.string.already_watched), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            prf.setBoolean(tostore, true);
                            Intent intent = getIntent();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        if(response.intern() == v2.intern()){

                            Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this,getString(R.string.server_problem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ItemsActivity.this,getString(R.string.server_problem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", App.getInstance().getUsername());
                params.put("points",App_Points);
                params.put("type",type);
                params.put("videoid",Image_Name_JSON);
                params.put("date","hehe");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_about, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                break;

            case R.id.share:
                shareURL();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // sharing
    void shareURL() {
        try
        { Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
            String sAux = getString(R.string.share_text)+"\n";
            sAux = sAux + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"\n";
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.choose_one)));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { //e.toString();
        }
    }


    public void JSON_HTTP_CALL(){

        RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        ParseJSonResponse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ItemsActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(RequestOfJSonArray);
    }

    public void ParseJSonResponse(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitle(json.getString(Image_Name_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageDescription(json.getString(Image_Decription_JSON));

                // Opening link in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(App_URL_JSON));

                // Adding message in array to display on RecyclerView click event.
                AppmessageArrayListForClick.add(json.getString(App_Message_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageUrl(json.getString(Image_URL_JSON));

                GetDataAdapter2.setAppPoints(json.getString(App_Points));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ListOfdataAdapter.add(GetDataAdapter2);

        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

    }

    void validate(){
        if (Config.Base_Url.intern() == Constants.API_License && !BuildConfig.DEBUG && Constants.release) {

            App.getInstance().logout();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(ItemsActivity.this);
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                award_items(data.getStringExtra("points"),data.getStringExtra("id"),getString(R.string.webpanel_credit));
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.getStringExtra("id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: When I need to execute php within JS i use Ajax. Do you know Ajax? I'm not sure if that can be used with Java. What it does: Ajax calls a single PHP script, which will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. Do you say, make own php script for every download link?

Comment: Any time Jasinka. Yes. For every different kind of PHP related script you could use AJAX to load/execute the PHP script. Inside your AJAX script you can handle success/error statements to do stuff. It is also possible to send POST data within your AJAX to your PHP script, so you can handle all the data you send to your PHP file, which means the PHP script could be dynamically created (instead of all different files)

Comment: If you wish I can write you an example.

Comment: You can write what will work with my activity?:) Where and what i need insert and how much it cost :D

Comment: Im not sure how to call ajax within java, do you know that? What I can write for you is an EXAMPLE on how ajax works and will call the php script. Of course for free, we are a community not a sales point :-p. But if you really need my assistance and would like to hire me on different steps, feel free to contact me on facebook. (search on my name)

Comment: Thanks for respond. I don't think i can implement ajax code alone.

Comment: Goodluck! If you need an example just let me know